# Caliburn.Micro TryClose closes every window

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have the following scenario:

- There is a login screen
- When the login is successful, it should close the login screen and start a new screen

I use this code in the Bootstrapper:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
  {
    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
      Initialize();
    }

    private IWindowManager windowManager = new WindowManager();    
    private MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      Init(new LoginViewModel());
    }

    public void Init(object viewModel)
    {
      windowManager.ShowWindow(viewModel);
    }
    public void Init2()
    {
      windowManager.ShowWindow(mainViewModel);
    }
}
```

This is my App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static AppBootstrapper Bootstrapper;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Bootstrapper = new AppBootstrapper();
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
    }
```

This is the method from Login viewmodel:

```
public class LoginViewModel: Screen
{
     public void DoLogin()
        {   

          if (LoginSuccessful)
          {       
            App.Bootstrapper.Init2();
            TryClose();
          }
       }
}
```

When `TryClose` is used, the second window is also closed and my application exits.

Why does it happen? How should I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked your code. At this point all I see is that TryClose causes an exception

```
Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.
```

It seems that *Caliburn* or even *System.Windows.Navigation* somehow under the hood goes to a different thread (I see that *ManagedThreadId* at constructor of **MainViewModel** differs from *ManagedThreadId* where **Init2** was called).

If you change your code to this one, then all performed as intended (*that is not quite perfect solution, just showing that it might work in some conditions*)

```
App.Bootstrapper.Init2();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { TryClose(); });
```

I don't think that it is a good practice to close last available window while trying to show another one. Just use some **shell** (even hide it if you dont want to see it at first place). And move there all your calls to **WindowManager** or/and **ActivateItem** if you would use **Conductor** inheritance. So you'll never be in such situation because you'll have at least one part of application on background, that would terminate only when you need it and not by accident.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I modified the application to follow the Conductor pattern and it works now.